# Why armored publick key from gpg locate-keys public differ from PGP public key server key?

Tags: public-key, openpgp, public-key-exchange

I was trying to verify signature of linux-firmware with GnuPG

1. `gpg --locate-keys jboyer@redhat.com`
2. I've got publick key with : `gpg --export --armor | less` This key have 88 lines
3. I used public PGP server and found public key at
   https://pgp.surfnet.nl/pks/lookup?search=jboyer%40redhat.com
4. I start to compare locate-keys key with one form public key server  -  they have same fingerpring, same at begining but don't match after a middle of short 88 lines version.
5. I imported key from PGP server and make  `gpg --export --armor | less` again - this key had 945 lines
6. `gpg --verify linux-firmware-20210208.tar.asc` showed same Primary
   key fingerpring and no errors for both keys - short 88 lines from gpg -locate-keys and long 945 lines from public server

I am comparing "PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK" of two same keys jboyer@redhat.com with same fingerprint but different length.

Why there is two public keys with same fingerprints and different length?

Comment: sumular question without proper answer
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60828/what-does-the-pgp-public-key-length-depend-on

Answer (score 0):

```
gpg --list-packets keyfile
```

showed me that "PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK" has complex format and keep some history within "signature packet" blocks that I don't understand for now.
Two keys has differen count of "signature packat" blocks.